# Calculating the probability of system failure in a distributed network

Tags: computer-science, distributed, time-complexity, high-availability, binomial-cdf

I am trying to build a mathematical model of the availability of a file in a distributed file-system. I posted this question at MathOverflow but this might as well be classified as a CS-question so I give it a shot here as well.

The system works like this: a node stores a file (encoed using erasure codes) at r*b remotes nodes, where r is the replication-factor and b is an integer constant. Erasure-coded files have the property that the file can be restored iff at least b of the remote nodes are available and return its part of the file.

The simplest approach to this is to assume that all remote nodes are independent of each other and have the same availability p. With these assumptions the availability of a file follows the Binomial distribution, i.e. [image: Binomial distribution]

Unfortunately these two assumptions can introduce a non-neligible error, as shown by this paper: [http://deim.urv.cat/~lluis.pamies/uploads/Main/icpp09-paper.pdf](http://deim.urv.cat/%7Elluis.pamies/uploads/Main/icpp09-paper.pdf).

One way to overcome the assumption that all nodes have the same availability is to calculate the probability of each possible combination of availaible/non-available node and take the sum of all these outcomes (which is sort of what they suggest in the paper above, just more formally than what I just described). You can see this approach as a binary tree with depth r*b and each leave is one possible combination of available/not-available nodes. The file's availability is the same thing as the probablity that you arrive at a leave with >=b available nodes. This approach is more correct but has a computational cost of [image: Ordo]. Also, it doesn't deal with the assumption of node independence.

Do you guys have any ideas of a good approximation which introduces less error than the binomial distribution-aproximation but with better computational cost than [image]?

You can assume that the availability-data of each node is a set of tuples consisting of `(measurement-date, node measuring, node being measured, succes/failure-bit)`. With this data you could for example calculate the correlation of the availability between the nodes and the availability variance.

Comment: What do you mean by "node independence"? Are you talking about a graph that represents the node network and failures of certain key nodes may partition the graph into topologically distinct subnetworks that cannot communicate among each other? Or do you assume the possibility that individual node failures may cause other nodes to fail, too (e.g., because they might be virtual machines located on the same physical machine)? Without clarifying the nature of the correlation it is impossible to suggest any models.

Comment: As a follow-up to the previous question it is important to specify if the reconstruction of the file is possible (read: meaningful) if a copy is available on a subnetwork of nodes able to communicate among each other. Or if you require access from a "root-node" to a subnetwork of at least b nodes in order to restore the file in question.

Comment: The last paragraph introduces the `measurement-date` as an additional property. This introduces a timescale into the system, where previously the system was assumed to be static. Previously, a node was either alive (probability `p`) or dead (probability `1-p`). With a time-scale the system may no longer be static and a certain mean-time-between-failures (for switching `alive` nodes to `dead`) and mean-time-between-repairs (the reverse) may become meaningful. If you have this situation, the probability for restoring a file becomes time-dependent.

Comment: As a followup to the time-dependent case, one would need to deal with m.t.b.f/r (mean-time-between-failures/repairs) instead of `p` and `1-p`, all of which become measurable quantities with a mean value (which may be node-dependent as you have pointed out) and an uncertainty (which reduces to zero if your log becomes long enough). I am pointing this out because in this case the question would be quite different from the original one (where you merely asked for a simplification formula in a specific situation).

Comment: Thanks for the great input! By "node independence" I mean the possibility that individual node failures may cause other nodes to fail. You can assume that the system is static (i.e. not time-dependent). The reason I added the time-variable was to show that I had the data to create a time-dependent model, however that is not a requirement; only an added bonus if it can be used without a too big performance hit.

Comment: There is no way you can possibly take all potential failure causes for a node into account. You would be better served to just measure the actuals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For large `r` and `b` you can use a method called Monte-Carlo integration, see e.g. [Monte Carlo integration on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_Integration) (and/or chapter 3.1.2 of SICP) to compute the sum. For small `r` and `b` and significantly different node-failure probabilities `p[i]` the exact method is superior. The exact definition of *small* and *large* will depend on a couple of factors and is best tried out experimentally.

**Specific sample code**: This is a very basic sample code (in Python) to demonstrate how such a procedure could work:

```
def montecarlo(p, rb, N):
    """Corresponds to the binomial coefficient formula."""
    import random
    succ = 0

    # Run N samples
    for i in xrange(N):
        # Generate a single test case
        alivenum = 0
        for j in xrange(rb):
            if random.random()<p: alivenum += 1
        # If the test case succeeds, increase succ
        if alivenum >= b: succ += 1
    # The final result is the number of successful cases/number of total cases
    # (I.e., a probability between 0 and 1)
    return float(succ)/N
```

The function corresponds to the binomial test case and runs `N` tests, checking if `b` nodes out of `r*b` nodes are alive with a probability of failure of `p`. A few experiments will convince you that you need values of `N` in the range of thousands of samples before you can get any reasonable results, but in principle the complexity is `O(N*r*b)`. The accuracy of the result scales as `sqrt(N)`, i.e., to increase accuracy by a factor of two you need to increase `N` by a factor of four. For sufficiently large `r*b` this method will be clearly superior.

**Extension of the approximation**: You obviously need to design the test case such, that it respects all the properties of the system. You have suggested a couple of extensions, some of which can be easily implemented while others can not. Let me give you a couple of suggestions:

1) In the case of distinct but uncorrelated `p[i]`, the changes of the above code are minimal: In the function head you pass an array instead of a single float `p` and you replace the line `if random.random()<p: alivenum += 1` by

```
if random.random()<p[j]: alivenum += 1
```

2) In the case of correlated `p[i]` you need additional information about the system. The situation I was referring to in my comment could be a network like this:

```
A--B--C
   |  |
   D  E
   |
   F--G--H
      |
      J
```

In this case `A` might be the "root node" and a failure of node `D` could imply the automatic failure with 100% probability of nodes `F`, `G`, `H` and `J`; while a failure of node `F` would automatically bring down `G`, `H` and `J` etc. At least this was the case I was referring to in my comment (which is a plausible interpretation since you talk about a tree structure of probabilities in the original question). In such a situation you would need modify the code that `p` refers to a tree structure and `for j in ...` traverses the tree, skipping the lower branches from the current node as soon as a test fails. The resulting test is still whether `alivenum >= b` as before, of course.

3) This approach will fail if the network is a cyclic graph that cannot be represented by a tree structure. In such a case you need to first create graph nodes that are either dead or alive and then run a routing algorithm on the graph to count the number of unique, reachable nodes. This won't increase the time-complexity of the algorithm, but obviously the code complexity.

4) Time dependence is a non-trivial, but possible modification if you know the m.t.b.f/r (mean-times-between-failures/repairs) since this can give you the probabilities `p` of either the tree-structure or the uncorrelated linear `p[i]` by a sum of exponentials. You will then have to run the MC-procedure at different times with the corresponding results for `p`.

5) If you merely have the log files (as hinted in your last paragraph) it will require a substantial modification of the approach which is beyond what I can do on this board. The log-files would need to be sufficiently thorough to allow to reconstruct a model for the network graph (and thus the graph of `p`) as well as the individual values of all nodes of `p`. Otherwise, accuracy would be unreliable. These log-files would also need to be substantially longer than the time-scales of failures and repairs, an assumptions which may not be realistic in real-life networks.

Comment: Thanks for your great response! I accepted your answer before the bounty expired but for some reason it says that the bounty was auto-accepted and only half the points where awarded. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming each node has a constant, known and independent availability rate, A divide and conquer approach come to mind.

Say you have `N` nodes.

1. Split them into two sets of `N/2` nodes.
2. For each side, compute the probability that any number of nodes (`[0,N/2]`) are down.
3. Multiply and sum these as needed to find the probability that any number (`[0,N]`) of the full set is down.

Step 2 can be done recursively and at the top level you can sum as need to find how often more than some number are down.

I don't know the complexity of this but if I has to guess, I'd say at or below `O(n^2 log n)`

---

The mechanics of this can be illustrated on a terminal case. Say we have 5 nodes with up times [image: p1...p5]. We can split this into segments `A` with[image: p1...p2] and `B` with [image: p3...p5]. We then can process these to find the "N nodes up" times for each segment:

For A:

[image: a_2]

[image: a_1]

[image: a_0]

For B:

[image: b_3]

[image: b_2]

The final results for this stage can be found by multiplying each of the `a`'s with each of the `b`'s and summing appropriately.

```
v[0] = a[0]*b[0]
v[1] = a[1]*b[0] + a[0]*b[1]
v[2] = a[2]*b[0] + a[1]*b[1] + a[0]*b[2]
v[3] =             a[2]*b[1] + a[1]*b[2] + a[0]*b[3]
v[4] =                         a[2]*b[2] + a[1]*b[3]
v[5] =                                     a[2]*b[3]
```

Comment: 1) How can you generalize this approach to the case of distinct failure probabilities? Example for `N=20`: If the probabilities that the three nodes N2, N3 and N7 are down is different from N1, N4 and N5 you still have complexity `O(2^N)` since you need to take into account all those distinct cases. 2) How can you generalize this approach to the case of node correlations? I.e., if a failure of node No. 2 results in a failure of nodes [N/2-1,...,N]? Such a non-locality cannot be handled efficiently in a recursive algorithm.

Comment: Your example case for A contains four terms, corresponding to a combination of four different cases leading to three possible outcomes. Complexity is thus `2^2=4`. Case B corresponds to four possible outcomes; had you explicitly written it down you would have b0, b1, b2, b3 with altogether `2^3=8` individual terms, each representing one of those eight cases. "Multiplying each of the `a`'s with each of the `b`'s and summing appropriately" generates six possible outcomes with altogether `2^5=32` terms. Thus, the complexity of your proposal is identical to the one in the original question.

Comment: @user8472: Multiplying each of the `a`'s with each of the `b`'s and summing appropriately generates six possible outcomes with altogether '4*3=12' terms. `a0*b0 ... a0*b3, a1*b0 ... a1*b3, a2*b0 ... a2*b3` for a much reduced complexity, and the improvement gets better higher up.

Comment: @BCS: I see how your approach performs a memoization of several terms. `a1` was two terms and `b1` three, so `v1` would actually be five "terms", not two. However, since you use those same combinations several times for `v1`...`v4` you can get away with computing them only once. Nonetheless, I don't see how this approach could generalize to correlations since (see e.g. the network in my suggestion 3 for nodes A-E) in that case a failure of node B would non-locally cut off all contributions from `b0`...`b3` and the assumption of independence underlying your memoization would be incorrect.

Comment: @user8472: I thought my description was rather explicit in that it reused terms, oh well. --- It only works for independent e.i. uncorrelated systems. OTOH for some systems, the splitting portion could be selected to match the correlations. Even if that can only be done a little bit, it could reduce it to a `O(b*2^(n/b)) problem.

Comment: @BCS: Yes, I agree. In some cases the complexity of correlated systems can be reduced by a polynomial factor (i.e., it might still be exponential, but with a favorable parameter). However, I don't see yet how the suggestion in your last comment gives rise to a specific algorithm to achieve it. The advantage of your suggestion is that the solution is exact.

On the other hand, the question poster has allowed an approximate solution if it is practical. For large systems (`r*b` > 1000s` or more) I don't see (yet) how an exact algorithm is practical.

Comment: @user8472: With a little manual setup, it might be possible to apply it. However I also don't see a way to automate it.